# newly installed debian gnome 3 hangs at shut down

Tags: debian, shutdown, freeze

I have just installed Debian Stable with gnome 3 on my msi laptop MSI GS 60 2PC-247XFR, when I shut down or quit session the system just freezes, here is a quote from my syslog file:

```
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian gnome-session[1175]: nm-applet-Message: PID 1 (we 
are 1361) sent signal 15, shutting down...
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources3[1216]: (evolution-source-registry:1348): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources3[1216]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian gnome-session[1175]: Received signal:15->'Complété'
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian gnome-session[1175]: Received signal:15->'Complété'
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar4[1216]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian gnome-session[1175]: Received signal:15->'Complété'
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian org.freedesktop.Tracker1[1216]: Received signal:15->'Complété'
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[1216]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[1216]: #033[31m[15:44:21.080633 WARNING]#033[0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:449: The connection is closed
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1216]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1216]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:1418): WARNING **: zeitgeist-fts.vala:252: The connection is closed
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian bluetoothd[579]: Terminating
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian ModemManager[581]: <info>  Caught signal, shutting down...
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian NetworkManager[584]: <info> caught signal 15, shutting down normally.
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian kernel: [  938.756284] wlan0: deauthenticating from 2a:a4:3c:bb:bc:36 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian wpa_supplicant[686]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=2a:a4:3c:bb:bc:36 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Sep 26 17:44:21 debian rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.4.2" x-pid="622" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
```

I don't understand very much from this message, would someone have an idea what the problem is  ?

EDIT: I have waited I while after the freeze instead of forcing to shut down, this message appeared:
[image]
Then it shutted down..
I could'nt find any trace of this message on my logs neither in kern.log or syslog

Comment: please post the result of `uname -r`

Comment: 3.16.0.4 amd 64, I totally messed up my system now I was installing nvidia driver, during the installation my system just freezed so I shutdown, and restart, I continued tutorial on the wiki doing the xorg config file thing etc ... I restarted it didn't boot .. So I boot in recovery mode I remove xorg config file, now It boots but I have error "Oh something wrong out log out etc.."

Comment: Oh no, I did the same thing - I mean the Nvidia drivers. I must have it re-installed then.

Comment: You mean you reinstalled debian ? Or the driver ?

Comment: I am also a Newbie, so I re-installed the whole system. Was a day's work.

Comment: So you had the exact same thing your system freezed during nvidia driver installation ? You've did something different after your reinstall ?

Comment: Debian Jessie 8.1, actually I have not installed Nvidia drivers again. Stayed with embedded drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have fixed the problem by changing "Primary Display" from nvidia to intel in my BIOS, no more freeze
I also noticed that "lspci -nn | grep VGA" does not detect my gtx860m neither "nvidia-detect", I'll open a new question later for that... it may be related..*

EDIT:
Now I fixed all my problems with nvidia, freeze etc..

--> It appears that the problem was coming from Nvidia Optimus, so I installed bumblebee (https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee), switch back "Primary Display" to nvidia.
The only bad thing is every time I need to use my graphic card for a runnable, I need to run it by typing "optirun" or "primusrun" ...

And FYI, if your system won't boot after nvidia driver installation (because you have nvidia optimus or something else went wrong...), go to recovery mode type `apt-get purge nvidia-*` then rename xorg.conf file. (no need to reinstall debian like I did)
If you still want to use graphic card install bumblebee by following instructions from the wiki link above

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest kernel from Debian should do the trick.

You can do this by:

```
apt-get install linux-image-flavour
```

More information on how to upgrade your kernel:
https://wiki.debian.org/HowToUpgradeKernel

Comment: So I reinstalled my system and tried this, it tells me that it can't find the package named "linux-image-flavour"